# Slack Bot not downloading files from direct message but is downloading when uploaded to a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, slack-api, botkit

So I have written a code to download a file from a slack bot

the code is

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var pDownload= function (url, dest){
  var slug = url.split('.com').pop();
  console.log(slug);
  var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "files.slack.com",
  "path": slug,
  "rejectUnauthorized": "false",
  "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer MYTOKEN"
    }
  }
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var responseSent = false; // flag to make sure that response is sent only once.

    https.get(options, response => {
      response.pipe(file);
      file.on('finish', () =>{
        file.close(() => {
          if(responseSent)  return;
          responseSent = true;
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }).on('error', err => {
        if(responseSent)  return;
        responseSent = true;
        reject(err);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.pDownload=pDownload;
example
pDownload('https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T7JRF8TCN-F7WDP24LV/analysis.r', './test/res.new')
   .then( ()=> console.log('downloaded file no issues...'))
   .catch( e => console.error('error while downloading', e));
```

however, if a user talks to the bot on direct message, the file that is downloaded only contains `'https://files-origin.slack.com/files-pri/T7JRF8TCN-F7WDP24LV/analysis.r found'` and not the contents

But if we are talking to the bot on a channel and upload a file, it correctly downloads the file and stores all the content to the file.

Why is this issue caused? and why is it redirecting to files-origin.slack.com when i have set the scope to `files:read` and `files:write:user`

Can the bot download the file when sent a Direct Message?

Comment: changing the hostname to `files-origin.slack.com` stores 'Requested file could not be found' in res.new

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? Where are you getting that url from? Are you using the private_download url that comes in on the direct message event? You can certainly access files that are sent to your bot via DM, something else is amiss here

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you tried sharing the file? Files belonging to other users need to be shared in a channel with your bot to give your bot access to it.

2) It looks to me that you are using a fixed hostname in your code. I would advise against it. Instead use the URL from the `url_private` property of the [file object](https://api.slack.com/types/file#authentication) for downloading. This will work together with your token as authentication.

Comment: there is no workaround other than the files being shared in a channel? The bot cant access any file from a direct message?

Comment: correct. files can only be accessed by their owner until they are shared.